# How does DHCP OFFER broadcast work?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, udp

I am trying to understand the concept of DHCP relay agents and was reading [this](https://www.netmanias.com/en/post/techdocs/6000/dhcp-network-protocol/understanding-dhcp-relay-agents) article. In section 3.2, talking about DHCP OFFER, it mentions that the DHCP relay agent replaces the destination ip to the broadcast IP :

*Destination IP address: The DHCP server sends the DHCP Offer message, with the destination address set as the relay agent IP address in the DHCP Discover message (1.1.1.254), to a DHCP relay agent. If the “Broadcast Flag” value in the message is 0, the relay agent replaces the value with the IP address allocated to the PC (Your IP field: 1.1.1.10) for unicasting. However, if the “Broadcast Flag” value is 1, the relay agent replaces it with the broadcast IP address (255.255.255.255) for broadcasting.*

My question is, since all the clients on the subnet receive the DHCP OFFER broadcast, how does the particular client recognize the OFFER is for itself, in other words, on what basis do other clients ignore the OFFER Message?

Comment: The client has already sent `DHCP Discover` and is waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [RFC2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131), section 4.1.1, there’s the following information:

> The client generates and records a random transaction identifier and
> inserts that identifier into the 'xid' field.  The client records its
> own local time for later use in computing the lease expiration.  The
> client then broadcasts the DHCPDISCOVER on the local hardware
> broadcast address to the 0xffffffff IP broadcast address and 'DHCP
> server' UDP port.
>
> If the 'xid' of an arriving DHCPOFFER message does not match the
> 'xid' of the most recent DHCPDISCOVER message, the DHCPOFFER message
> must be silently discarded.  Any arriving DHCPACK messages must be
> silently discarded.

I believe this is the information you were looking for. It is not specific to DHCP relay agents.

Elsewhere in the document, it is also specified that unless the client explicitly requests the DHCP server do not, responses are sent to the unicast layer 2 address of the client. To the client, the DHCP relay agent behaves like as if it were the DHCP server itself.

Comment: Thank you so much!